# passing form value to URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

appending a form field value to the next url.

I am trying to pass a form field value on form submission to the next page URL.

So far;
**The form snippet:**

```
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label> 
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" onchange="update()" type="text">
```

At the script section where the url for the next page is created;

```
  <script>
      var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;

      function update() {
        fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
      }
      document.getElementById('thankPage').value = 'https://example.com/thank' + fn;
    </script>
```

The fn is currently not passing to the next url. However, if I pre-fill the first_name field, the fn is passed correctly. So I am assuming the fn value being used is not updated and its using its initial value.

I tried initializing fb outside update() so its a global var. Unless I am mistaken? And I am assuming when  '+ fn' occurs, its using the updated value of fn, which currently is not the case.

Comment: Why isn't the url being set within the update function?

Comment: What has an id of "thankPage"? A `<a...>...</a>`  link? The `href` of a link is not a `value` you can set that way.

Comment: @kshetline, looks like question's author tries to assign value to 'thankPage` once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the value of `thankPage` outside the scope of the `update` function, which means the value will be set only once (most likely when the page is loaded). This is why it only works when the first_name field is pre-filled.

If you want the value to change whenever the first_name field is updated you'd have to move the code within the scope of the `update` function.

e.g.

```
function update() {
    var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    document.getElementById('thankPage').value = 'https://example.com/thank' + fn;
}

update();
```

```js
function update() {
  var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  document.getElementById('thankPage').value = 'https://example.com/thank/' + fn;
}

update();
```

```html
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" onchange="update()" type="text" value="name">
<br><br>
<input id="thankPage" style="width:300px;" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your piece of code you update value of `thankPage` only once. Move `document.getElementById('thankPage').value = 'https://example.com/thank' + fn;` inside your `update(..)`. Moreover, as for me you not need variable fn

```
function update() {
  document.getElementById('thankPage').value = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the value of `thankPage` inside the update() function. It will update the value after you finish the changing the value in input field. If you want to update it while you are typing, use `onkeydown` instead of `onchange`.

```js
function update() {
  var fn = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  document.getElementById('thankPage').innerHTML = 'https://example.com/thank/' + fn;
}
```

```html
<label for="first_name">First Name</label> 
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" onchange="update()" type="text">
</br>
<span id="thankPage"></span>
```